# CUDALink gives wrong results but no error on Mathematica 13.2

Tags: cudalink, cuda

I installed Mathematica 13.2 under Linux Mint 21.1 (Ubuntu 22.04). After installing cuda-toolkit-11-8. I get True as answer from CUDAQ[], but if I start some calculations I get wrong results.

Following the Documentation examples I can produce errors in CUDAMap, CUDADot and many other CUDA functions. There are no error messages at all just wrong results.

Example:
[image]

With older Mathematica Versions CUDA was running fine.

Has anybody experienced the same behavior? Can someone give a hint how to fix this?

Update:
I tried to follow the solution BertRAMAerts provided. I created the following script and started Mathematica with it. Unfortunately there was no change in the results
[image]

What really puzzles me, is that there is no error message at all. Simply wrong results which is very dangerous to my point of view. If someone is using this functions in a more sophisticated code he can run into serious problems without knowing the root cause.

Comment: On Windows with a 1080ti on Mathematica 13.2, the difference between CUDA and CPU results is `{0., 0., 0., 0., 5.55112*10^-17, 1.11022*10^-16, 0., 0., 0., 0.}` so they pretty much agree. Maybe it's something wrong in Linux only? Do you see a similar result with OpenCL? - try running this https://pastebin.com/WFiNF4eH

Comment: Thank you your suggestion I will try it tomorow ...

Comment: I tried the code you provided but OpenCL fails already at OpenCLQ[]. I get OpenCLFunctionLoad::invplt: OpenCLLink platform is invalid. when I run the function. I tried different CUDA Versions 11.7, 11.8 and  12. All causing different errors. CUDA 11.2 is not available for my Ubuntu 22.04. Does somebody know a workaround?

Comment: Can I use CUDA functionality in Mathematica with CUDA Version 11.7 or 11.8? Or do I have to find a way to make 11.2 run on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: I checked the cuda functionality again with Mathematica 13.2 and 13.2.1. While on Windows It runs fine with cuda toolkit 11.8 I still get the same error under Ubuntu. The OpenCLLink package does not load with the follwoing error message: "One or more OpenCL resource failed to load."

Comment: OpenCLQ[] is broken because OpenCLLink is broken. See: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2730946 (my comments as Zaqu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved with Mathematica 13.3.1. Thank you all for you help and input.

I run the configuration below on Linux Mint 21.2 and can see no problems/errors so far

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu 22.10 laptop with nVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 I get correct results:

[image]

Please note I start Mathematica from terminal with:

```
cat mathematica.sh

export NVIDIA_DRIVER_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-tls.so.525.89.02
export CUDA_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
export PATH=/home/bert/bin_gcc_11:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin:$PATH$
g++ --version
mathematica &
```

Please always verify if CUDA is OK via:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. Please find my the update to my original post, where I tried your approach.

Comment: @Tschibi Please check my updated answer

Comment: CUDA Toolkit 12.2 released today. Mathematica 13.3.0 released today.
CUDA via Mathematica is a real disaster. CUDAMap, CUDADot give invalid results.
When specifying a kernel function in code, results seem correct though.

Comment: More details on https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2946813?p_p_auth=7MWngAvx